# LINQ query to return list where condition is based on another table

Tags: sql-server, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have two tables `Cars` and `Booking`.

I want the following SQL query's equivalent in LINQ and I'm struggling with it

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CARS 
WHERE Car_id NOT IN (SELECT Car_Id 
                     FROM Bookings 
                     WHERE JourneyCompletion = 'OnGoing');
```

The result should be a list of cars. How can I achieve this in Linq?

Comment: You Must **NOT** Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In English!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try Below Code:**

```
var Q1 = (from row in DbContext.Bookings where row.JourneyCompletion=='OnGoing' select row).ToList();
var Q2 = (from row in DbContext.CARS.where(n=> !n.Car_Id.Contains(n.Car_id))).ToList();
```

Comment: I Will Try And Update If It Works..